# Microsoft Query Wizard specify Column Filter that is greater than or equal to 30 days from today

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003, query

I'd like to use Microsoft Query Wizard specify Column Filter that is greater than or equal to 30 days from today. Is there reserved name that I can use, like TODAY-30 under the filter criteria?

Comment: Which database is MS Query talking to ?

Comment: It's an Oracle DB, but I'm using BMC's AR System ODBC driver. I just found out that the driver does not have any date functions built in to it, so I can not do what I'd like to do. :(